# Custom TypeScript rules in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

In the documentation (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/#header-1) TypeScript isn't listed as a supported language for custom rules but JavaScript is. Because of this is it possible to use the JavaScript runner to execute custom TypeScript rules?

If not, is anyone aware of how to do more advanced rules with tslint or is there an alternative to SonarQube that would allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `SonarQube` visit [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/typescript/) and [here](https://beerandserversdontmix.com/2018/02/03/importing-custom-typescript-tslint-rules-into-sonarqube/), it will help you.

> and I found this, it’s not possible, the concept of external issues
>   appeared in SonarQube 7.2. Upgrade to the new LTS 7.9

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the tslint import route. I've just seen this: https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/commit/175e1fef5e7092a78fab2ba4a3fa60ec5095e80c which means the JavaScript route won't work any more anyway.